# How to keep multiple instances of MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have installed xampp for Linux. It's working fine and my mysql is also working fine.

I have another application that also uses mysql but i need to stop mysql server if i run Xampp. However, Stopping mysql server this way halts the other application and it throws the following error:

```
⇝ OperationalError: (OperationalError) (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)") None None
```

How can I stop this error and keep both applications running on same Mysql server. Both use a single mysql server instance, but I need to halt one in order to run another.

Can any one help me resolving this issue. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: have you installed two instances of mysql server ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need more mysql servers, may be four or five (just kidding).

First, two applications can work with the same server using different database/username => you don't need two mysql servers. If you need, you are wrong step before.

Second, you'd probably better to use native apps for you linux distro (ie mysql/apache/whatever-comes-with-xampp). If for whatever reason you have to stick up with xampp (what I believe is not true), don't use native mysql/apache/etc.